# Mongo - build table from two collections

Tags: php, oop, object, mongodb

I am trying to replicate what would be a left join in MySql in Mongo.  I have a collection named Clients and another collection name Orders.

In the clients collection is have:

```
client_PK, FirstName, LastName, Company
```

In the orders collection I have:

```
order_PK, client_fk, OrderDate, OrderAmount,
```

So i know that can use embedded documents but for the sake of this question i am looking to use the reference model.

My question is, using these two collections how would I construct a table or object similar to a left join in mysql?  I know this is a document db not a relational db but im using sql language just to give you an idea of what im trying to accomplish.  In MySql it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN clients ON clients.client_PK = orders.client_fk
```

with this i could now construct a table that looked like:

```
FirstName | LastName | Company | OrderDate | OrderAmount
```

then i could repeat the rows using a while loop to display all orders and display the clients name with the order.  Again i know mongo isn't a relational db but i am assuming there is a way simulate a table using two collections.

Thank you.

Comment: Please stop tagging your questions "couchdb." It wastes people's time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly want to be storing these data all in the same MongoCollection (even in just a denormalization collection).

If you absolutely can't do that, though, *and* if your set is small, you can do something similar to this (since you asked about PHP):

```
<?php
// gather orders
$orders = iterator_to_array($mongodb->orders->find());
$joinedOrders = array();
// gather clients
foreach ($db->clients->find() as $client) {
    // iterate orders (like a left join)
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        // make a "joinedOrders" record for each join match
        if ($order['client_fk'] == $client['client_PK']) {
            $joinedOrders[] = array_merge($order, $client);
        }
    }
}
// result is now in $joinedOrders
```

This is, however, almost always a bad idea. (-: You really should be denormalizing your data, or using a relational database to store/query relational data.

Answer (score 1):

> i am assuming there is a way simulate a table using two collections

MongoDB does not have any tool for doing this. You are basically going to have "roll your own" joins. At the basic level, this means that you will have to write nested `for` loops and build a result set in your code.

Doing this type of "extra logic" is pretty common in MongoDB because of the lack of joins. If you're seeing this pattern a lot, you may want to consider using SQL for part of your data.

Comment: I am a newbie, i understand what you are suggesting I do but im not sure how to "roll" or write it.  Can you give an example in php?  Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at @scoates answer, he has some basic code. However, if you cannot write that code on your own, I'm going to warn against using MongoDB. MongoDB is a powerful product but it does not have a lot of tooling and it does not offer all of the features of SQL. Nested joins is the least of the extra work you will need to do, Map/Reduce is significantly more complex.